# How to narrow the line spacing of different confidence intervals of one object in forestplot

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I have two confidence intervals per object. However, the spacing between two lines representing the same group is so large that the bottom line bleeds into the next group.

I tried to set `lineheight="auto"` which results in a long graph that does not work for me.

How can I adjust the height of two OR lines?

[image: The forestplot now]

```
forestplot(labeltext =as.matrix(rbind(header,umresult[seq(1,38,2),c(1,23,20)])),  
       legend = c("method1", "method2"),
       mean =cbind(c(NA,umresult$or[seq(1,38,2)]),c(NA,umresult$or[seq(2,38,2)])),
       lower=cbind(c(NA,umresult$or_lci[seq(1,38,2)]),c(NA,umresult$or_lci[seq(2,38,2)])),
       upper=cbind(c(NA,umresult$or_uci[seq(1,38,2)]),c(NA,umresult$or_uci[seq(2,38,2)])),
       graph.pos = 3,
       graphwidth = unit(70,"mm"),
       is.summary=c(T,rep(F,19)),
       txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label=gpar(cex=1),
                      ticks=gpar(cex=1.1), 
                      xlab=gpar(cex=1), 
                      title=gpar(cex=2)),
       hrzl_lines=list("2" = gpar(lwd=1, col="#444444")),
       zero = 1,
       xticks = c(0,1,2,3),
       clip=c(0,3),
       lwd.zero=1,
       lwd.ci=0.5,
       lwd.xaxis=1, 
       lty.ci=1,
       ci.vertices=TRUE, ci.vertices.height = 0.2,
       lineheight="auto", 
       line.margin=unit(4, 'mm'),
       colgap=unit(7, 'mm'),
       boxsize =0.1,
       col=fpColors(zero = "#e22e2a",lines = "BLACK",text=c("black"),box = c("#006400", "#CD853F")),
       #fn.ci_norm = forestcolor,
       grid =T)
```

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried and reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just added my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it works if I delete the parameter `line.margin`, though I don't know the reason.